# Adding dates as tab titles

Tags: java, android, date, tabs

I am very new to coding and I was wondering if someone could walk me through the best way to be able get live updating dates as my tabbed titles in the format shown in the picture, for example "MON 04 APR"

By "live updating" I mean the values on the tabs change when the current date changes

I down this route but not sure how to get tomorrows date any ideas.

```
`java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 java.util.Date;

`public class TabDate {
public static void main(String[] args){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
    String date =sdf.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(date);`
```

also how to I make it the title of my tabs?

```
'@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String title=" ";
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            title="Selection";
            break;
        case 1:
            title="Today";
            break;
        case 2:
            title="Tomorrow";
            break;
        case 3:
            title="Mon 04 Apr";
            break;
        case 4:
            title="Tue 05 Apr";
            break;
        case 5:
            title="Wed 06 Apr";
            break;
    }

    return title;`
```

Comment: By "live updating" do you mean the values on the tabs change when the current date changes? Please edit your question to describe exactly what you want.

Comment: I need a little more help than this to be honest

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd MMM");
    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String result = formatter.format(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

try looking at this documentation.

In order to get a date and format it in a certain way you might want to use Java's SimpleDateFormat class.

```
public String formatDate(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
    return format.format(date);
}
```